# Play locally stored video only once using am start on an android device and check if playback is completed

Tags: android

I am automating tasks to play videos in android device. I am starting the locally stored videos using a shell script as below

```
#!/bin/bash
video_src=$1
video_src_and=$2
for entry in "$video_src"/*
do
   echo ${entry##*/}
   for videos in "$entry"/*
   do
     echo Playing $video_src_and${entry##*/}${videos##*/}
     adb logcat -c
     adb logcat > logcat_playback.txt&
     adb shell am start -n com.google.android.apps.photos/.pager.HostPhotoPagerActivity -d file:///"$video_src_and${entry##*/}/${videos##*/}"
     while ! grep -q -i 'saw output EOS' logcat_playback.txt 
     do
        sleep 10
     done
   done
done
```

Currently the observation is the video being played is looping. 
Hence I am using grep to detect End of stream and start the next playback.

I need to play the video only once.
Also can we check using adb commands that video playback is completed or not ?

Comment: update the question with your code !

Comment: I don't think that google photos app sends any kind of broadcasts when video has been played. So probably only solution for you is to create your own app which does that.

Comment: I am not specific about the app being used for playing videos. Its just the example I have used it. My main intention is to play the video only once rather than looping the same video and to check the status of video playback. In the above script I am grepping for EOS of file. I am looking for some simpler approach.